# In mercurial, how to deal with identically named file and directory in two revisions?

Tags: mercurial

The problem can be trivially illustrated:

```
hg init temp
cd temp
touch a
hg ci -A -m file
hg rm a
mkdir a
hg ci -m dir
hg up -r0
```

The last command fails with `abort: Is a directory: a` (or a more cryptic `Access is denied` on Windows).

Is there any workaround?

I ran into this exact problem when converting legacy code base. I really need to fully automate the conversion since I have dozens of versions of a huge code base to deal with, and synonymous file/dir can happen at any time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add:

```
hg purge
```

before the last update, to get rid of the empty directory.  Note that even if you had added the directory, it would still not be tracked; Mercurial does not track empty directories (it only tracks non-empty ones implicitly).

`purge` removes "Unknown files" and "Empty directories".

Comment: just a clarification: mercurial does not track directories at all.

Comment: @zerkms, true, but non-empty directories are tracked implicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the bundled extension.